# How to check if a date falls within the next 7 days

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
function validateDate() {               
    serverDateTime="2012-11-23 17:06:46";
    txtDate.value="30-Nov-2012"

    if (how i check here){
        alert("Appointment can be fixed for next seven days only from current day.");                       
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

I'm getting serverDateTime on master page load and access that variable in all pages and comparing serverDateTime with txtDate.value how do I validate Appointment can be fixed for next seven days only from current day.

I M USING THIS CODE BUT STILL NOT WORKING

```
    function validateDate()
            {           
                var dateDifference;
                pickedDate = Date.parse(txtDate.value.replace(/-/g, " "));
                todaysDate = new Date(serverDateTime);
                todaysDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
                dateDifference = Math.abs(Number(todaysDate) - pickedDate);
                //7 Days=604800000ms
                if (dateDifference > 604800000)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
//Get the date value of next week.
var today = new Date(serverDateTime);
var nextWeek = Date.parse(new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() + 7));

//If nextWeek is smaller (earlier) than the value of the input date, alert...
if (nextWeek < Date.parse(txtDate.value)){
    alert("Appointment can be fixed for next seven days only from current day.");                       
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
}
```

[Fiddle example. Slightly modified](http://fiddle.jshell.net/9Gpsk/3/).

Comment: cerebrus i have to compare txtDate.value with serverDateTime  NOT TO COMPARE WITH CLIENT DATE

Comment: Whoops, forgot that variable.
This should do it. It makes a `Date` object out of the `serverDateTime` string, adds a week, then compares it to the input.
Those caps are completely unnecessary.

Comment: That is because `txtDate.value = "30-Nov-2012"` is within 7 days. The code works.
Try `txtDate.value="5-Dec-2012"`

I assume `txtDate` is indeed a object?

Comment: when i debug var today=NAN and var nextWeek=NAN

Comment: Of course `today` is not a number, it's a `Date` object.

What are you doing with the code?

Comment: @Cerbrus: that fiddle doesn't work. I get true for whatever date goes in. I've not bothered debugging but are you sure your date parsing is doing what it should?

Comment: @Chris
What browser are you using? the Fiddle is returning `true
false` for me, and alerting before the false. (Chrome here) Edit: I see, Firefox's returning `true true`. Darnit

Comment: FF 17.0. An alert on the datetime suggests that it considers the date string to be invalid after attempting to load it from the string. Was just looking for the spec to see what it should accept...

Comment: it always return true cerbrus

Comment: Found it:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Examples
It's an invalid input, indeed.
@lax, try to see if you can get a date returned in one of the formats, in the link.

Comment: I M CHECKING IN IE8 MY PROJECT IS IE DEPENDENT

Comment: SEE QUETION I USE CODE FOR CHECKING BUT THAT ALSO NOT WORKING

Comment: @lax. Switch off your [Capslock]. We're trying to help you here, but you're not being very friendly about our input.
I edited the fiddle and updated the link. This one works properly in all the browsers I have installed here, but you will have to change the date format you're getting from the server.

Comment: Also for the ecmascript standard (the above might have implementation specific stuff): http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2  - it looks at a glance like only iso standard string formats like `2012-11-23T12:56:42` are going to be accepted by everything. Other stuff seems like it will be implementation specific (though a lot of implementations might do it right). the other option of course is if you know your input string format to just use a fucntion to manually extract the component parts to use in a date constructor.

Comment: You would have to manually parse the string and assemble the `Date` object for it. It should be easier to change your server's output.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(serverDateTime.AddDays(7) < txtDate)
{
  //Your Code
}
```

Comment: i have to compare txtDate.value with serverDateTime  NOT TO COMPARE WITH CLIENT DATE

Answer (score 0):

[See JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/eZET9/3/)

```
//Set 1 day in milliseconds
var one_day=1000*60*60*24;
var serverDateTime= new Date("2012-11-23 17:06:46");
var newDate = new Date("30-Nov-2012"); //replace with txtDate.value

//Calculate difference btw the two dates, and convert to days
var diff = Math.ceil((newDate.getTime() - serverDateTime.getTime())/one_day);
if(diff >= 7)
{
    alert("7 days");   
}
else
{
    alert("Not up to 7 days");
}
​
```

This is just to guide you. You can [read more here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/datedifference.shtml)

Comment: NOT GIVING ME ALERT USING ABOVE CODE

Comment: var serverDateTime = new Date("2012-11-23 17:06:46"); GETTING NAN

Comment: It's not using alert. I'll update. You still need to adapt this you to your scenario. I have only shown you how to get the difference

Comment: serverDateTime  getting NAN

Comment: Apparently, IE and Firefox only accept date strings formatted following the ecmascript standard @Cris linked me to, below: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Before you can compare dates, they must be dates...
In your example they are both strings so try something like this :

```
function validateDate() {  
  var one_day=1000*60*60*24; 
  serverDateTime="2012-11-23 17:06:46";
  txtDate.value="30-Nov-2012"

  var _dtSvr = Date.parse(serverDateTime);
  var _dtTxt = Date.parse(txtDate.value);

  if (((_dtTxt - _dtSvr)/one_day) > 7){
    alert("Appointment can be fixed for next seven days only from current day.");                       
    return false;
  }else{
    return true;
  }
}
```

Try this and change the values of txtDate.value. 
I also recommend that you do extra verification on the formats in order for your dates to be correctly understood.
Have a look on [MDN Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for all the details of date/time in javascript

EDIT

I tried this exactly in the Chrome (v23.xxx) console :

```
function validateDate(serverDateTime, txtDate)
        {           
            var dateDifference;
            pickedDate = Date.parse(txtDate.replace(/-/g, " "));
            todaysDate = new Date(serverDateTime);
            todaysDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            dateDifference = Math.abs(Number(todaysDate) - pickedDate);
            //7 Days=604800000ms
            if (dateDifference > 604800000)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Then I tried this :

```
validateDate("2012-11-23 17:06:46", "30-Nov-2012")
```

which returns "true"
and tried this :

```
validateDate("2012-11-23 17:06:46", "30-Dec-2012")
```

which returns "false"

It looks like this answers your question and further issues are nothing to do with the algo but more like how your browser interprets it and how you manage it.

Comment: Did you read up on the link I provided to see the Date/Time formats accepted by your Javascript and see if there is not a culture specific issue? Most examples give here work for several people and browsers, why not yours?

Comment: To be more precise : what browser do you use (name and version)? I noticed differences between Firefox and Chrome... Somehow, I always forget about Internet Explorer ;)